# uploading csv file into Django model

Tags: python, django, pandas

I'm working on a Django app and need to import a CSV file into the Django model.

What's the proper way to get around this?

I was planning to use `pandas` to read the CSV and then saving into models with `bulk_create`. But not sure if there will be any performance issues as the dataset can get bigger.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The solution is right. You can use `csv` lib instead of pandas. `import csv`

Comment: @MahdiNamaki I tried to import csv with 1.79 lakhs records and it took 43.59178614616394 seconds. I don't think `pandas` would be a good fit for larger datasets in web application

Comment: you could try ujson. it is a fast module built in C

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://concisecoder.io/2019/04/19/avoid-memory-issues-with-djangos-bulk_create/

```py
from itertools import islice
from my_app.models import MyModel
def create_data(data):
    bulk_create(MyModel, generator())

def bulk_create(model, generator, batch_size=10000):
    """
    Uses islice to call bulk_create on batches of
    Model objects from a generator.
    """
    while True:
        items = list(islice(generator, batch_size))
        if not items:
            break
        model.objects.bulk_create(items)

def generator(data):
    for row in data:
        yield MyModel(field1=data['field1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems when using a large dataset, like performance, time and fake data.

The main solution for that is "chunking" that means divide your dataset as chunks and then do the operations

sample code to make the chunks of the large dataset

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset_name.csv", chunksize=100000)
chunks = []  

# Each chunk is in dataframe format
for chunk in dataset:  
   filtered_chunk = chunk_filtering(chunk)
   chunks.append(filtered_chunk)

filtered_data = pd.concat(chunks)
```

After that load the data normally.